# How to get rid of touch and hold feedback circle on Samsung tablet

Tags: windows-7, touch

I've got a multitouch app running in the web browser on a windows 7 tablet. Part of it's functionality requires touch and hold (single touch). The app already has it's own feedback indicator for this gesture, but the OS (or samsung?) ring appears around the finger when holding after about 1000 MS.

I'm not sure if it is samsung or the OS. Any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, ok there are two settings. Get rid of press and hold for right click for both pen and touch. Sucks that you can't have that functionality without showing the indicator ring.